# Python Gspread 401 error after a period of time

Tags: python, http-status-code-401, gspread

I am trying to write a program to grab stats i have recorded in google spreadsheets and write them to a text file to be read and displayed on a stream.  The program works fine for the most part but every once in a while it crashes with the following.  It looks like an oauth issue but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "updatestats.py", line 67, in <module>
    losses = worksheet.acell('C4').value
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 312, in acell
    return self.cell(*(self.get_int_addr(label)))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\models.py", line 328, in cell
    self._cell_addr(row, col))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\client.py", line 269, in get_cells_cell_id_feed
    r = self.session.get(url)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\httpsession.py", line 75, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\gspread\httpsession.py", line 71, in request
    response.status_code, response.content))
gspread.exceptions.HTTPError: 401: b'<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\n<H1>Unauthorized</H1>\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n'
```

Here's my code:

```
import requests, gspread
import os
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def authenticate_google_docs():
    f = open(os.path.join('Culling-89b347145798.p12'), 'rb')
    SIGNED_KEY = f.read()
    f.close()
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials('*****@gmail.com', SIGNED_KEY, scope)

    data = {
        'refresh_token' : '****************************',
        'client_id' : '*******************************',
        'client_secret' : '****************************',
        'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
    }

    r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data = data)
    credentials.access_token = eval(r.text)['access_token']

    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    return gc
gc = authenticate_google_docs()
sh = gc.open("The Culling")
worksheet = sh.worksheet("Stats")
while(1==1):
    solo = input('Was it a solo game? ')
    win = input('Were you victorious? ')
    kills = input('How many kills did you get? ')
    dmg = input('How much damage dvid you do? ')
    if solo != "y":
        if win == "y":
            bAlive = input('Did you both survive? ')
    gun = input('Did you find a gun? ')

    if solo == "n":
        if win == "y":
            wins = worksheet.acell('B2').value
            worksheet.update_acell('B2', int(wins)+1)
            if bAlive == "y":
                doubleWins = worksheet.acell('D2').value
                worksheet.update_acell('D2',int(doubleWins)+1)
        if win != "y":
            losses = worksheet.acell('C2').value
            worksheet.update_acell('C2', int(losses)+1)

    if solo == "j":
        if win == "y":
            wins = worksheet.acell('B3').value
            worksheet.update_acell('B3', int(wins)+1)
            if bAlive == "y":
                doubleWins = worksheet.acell('D3').value
                worksheet.update_acell('D3',int(doubleWins)+1)
        if win != "y":
            losses = worksheet.acell('C3').value
            worksheet.update_acell('C3', int(losses)+1)

    if solo == "t":
        if win == "y":
            wins = worksheet.acell('B4').value
            worksheet.update_acell('B4', int(wins)+1)
            if bAlive == "y":
                doubleWins = worksheet.acell('D4').value
                worksheet.update_acell('D4',int(doubleWins)+1)
        if win != "y":
            losses = worksheet.acell('C4').value
            worksheet.update_acell('C4', int(losses)+1)

    if gun == "y":
        if win == "y":
            if solo != "y":
                gWins = worksheet.acell('M9').value
                worksheet.update_acell('M9', int(gWins)+1)
            if solo == "y":
                gWins = worksheet.acell('M10').value
                worksheet.update_acell('M10', int(gWins)+1)
        if win == "n":
            if solo != "y":
                gLosses = worksheet.acell('N9').value
                worksheet.update_acell('N9', int(gLosses)+1)
            if solo == "y":
                gLosses = worksheet.acell('N10').value
                worksheet.update_acell('N10', int(gLosses)+1)

    if solo != "y":
        damage = worksheet.acell('D9').value
        worksheet.update_acell('D9', int(dmg)+int(damage))
        klls = worksheet.acell('B9').value
        worksheet.update_acell('B9', int(klls)+int(kills))
        if win == "y":
            streak = worksheet.acell('J9').value
            bestStreak = worksheet.acell('I9').value
            if bestStreak == streak:
                worksheet.update_acell('I9',int(streak)+1)
            worksheet.update_acell('J9',int(streak)+1)
        if win != "y":
            worksheet.update_acell('J9',0)
    if solo == "y":
        damage = worksheet.acell('D10').value
        worksheet.update_acell('D10', int(dmg)+int(damage))
        klls = worksheet.acell('B10').value
        worksheet.update_acell('B10', int(klls)+int(kills))
        if win == "y":
            streak = worksheet.acell('J10').value
            bestStreak = worksheet.acell('I10').value
            if bestStreak == streak:
                worksheet.update_acell('I10',int(streak)+1)
            worksheet.update_acell('J10',int(streak)+1)
        if win != "y":
            worksheet.update_acell('J10',0)
```

Comment: Facing the same problem .... will try to re-authenticate after some time and post my results.

Comment: @PKaura, did that work for you?

Comment: @NTAWolf don't remember now, it has been close to a year, but I have some recollection, authenticating after some time does work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solve this yet, there is answer for similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914349/python-gspread-request-error-401). Once you got 401, then login again to solve it.

```
gc.login()
```